# PBR lighting is broken with a ambiant light, not with a directionnal light

Tags: three.js, 3d, pbr

I have a problem with our ThreeJS PBR. I have created a simple threeJS on [ThreeJS Editor](https://threejs.org/editor/) project with two cubes where I set a PBR material on both cube with the following textures:

- [My ORM map used in the OA map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgB5x.jpg), used for the metalic map, and the roughtness map and the AO map.
- [My normal map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4702.jpg)
- [My base color map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP4kc.jpg)
  The left cube has the metalness to 0, et the right one has the metalness to 1.

[Here is the result with an ambiant light](https://i.stack.imgur.com/novHS.png), the right cube is wierd, the output of the lighting doesn't match with what we want.
[Here is the result with a directionnal light](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVnJI.png), where the output of the right cube has a correct lighting

Why the output of my PBR lighting is wierd on a ambiant light ? But works with a directionnal light ?